# wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 in CLLocation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

locationManager.delegate = self;

locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move

locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m

[locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

When I am using this code in viewWillAppear i face this warning sometime and so that
the delegate method of that no called

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you use this bellow code intsed of your code...

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

locationManager.delegate = self;

locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move

locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m

[locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

you define `startUpdatingHeading` method first after you allocate the locationManager object....so may be this problem about this error....
If again this problem occur then leave the comment ....
Hope this help you....
:-)

Answer (score 0):

Something in your `-viewWillAppear:` method is taking more time than the animation that is displaying your view takes. If it is the `CLLocationManager` maybe you can start it from a background thread or on the next turn of the run loop.

```
dispatch_queue_t q = /* bg queue or main queue */
dispatch_async(q, ^{
    /* your CLLocationManager code */
});
```